# How to avoid ajax sending multiple times to server in woocommerce?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have developed custom gateway plugin in woocommerce. I am submitting the place order through jquery ajax and getting the response throgh success event and process the payment. While submitting ajax submitting multipule times to 3rd party server. how to avoid it.

```
function payment_field(){ ?>
<script>
var success = function(response){
jquery.ajax({
handle the response through ajax and redirect the page
})
}

 jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function (e) {
//submitinfo to the server
//Pblm with sending multiple times to server
 }
```

[please check with the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjO0X.jpg)

Comment: what's with the `<script>` tag in the body of the function?

Comment: where do you call payment_field() and how many times?

Answer (score 0):

Move your submit event outside any function or loop

```
jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function (e) {
//submitinfo to the server
 }
function payment_field(){
//rest of the code...
```

Comment: If i seperate it it wont work  bcoz of the script given by the client inside i am sending the submit billinginfo to their server

Comment: i don't understand why exactly can't you do that?